# Which movie will we watch?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, movies

A friend invited me to a movie night. But instead of telling me which movie we are going to watch, she just gave me a bunch of movie tickets:

[image]

Can you tell me which movie we will watch?

---

**Hint 1:**

> The searched movie title is not on one of the tickets.

**Hint 2:**

> The shown arrangement of the tickets is random and irrelevant to the solution. However, you have to bring the tickets in a certain order.

**Hint 3:**

> There is no [knowlege](/questions/tagged/knowlege) or [movies](/questions/tagged/movies) tag. You don't have to know that movie. The name is hidden within the information of the tickets.

**Hint 4:**

> The movie title consists of two words. You have to use all tickets, but it's not one letter per ticket.

- **Hint 4.1:**

  > You have to use all tickets for each of the two words.

**Hint 5:**

> Use the directions you get from the times in the right order and you will get to the answer.

Comment: There's no comments on any of the answers indicating if any reasoning is close or correct.  How about a hint? :)

Comment: @m1gp0z I added two hints. They might be already obvious, but I don't want to hint to much. There is not so much missing to the solution. Someone just needs to have the right idea and I don't know how to hint it without giving it away.

Comment: @formica may be the answer is "Searching" as your hint 1 "The searched movie title is not on one of the tickets." so its obvious movie name is "Searching"

Comment: @formica Is there maths involved here?

Comment: @JamieBarker No, you don't have to calculate something.

Comment: I've spent way more time on this than I care to admit! :P any chance of a 5th clue?

Comment: @Dmihawk It is also hard to come up with a hint, that doesn't make it too obvious. But there you go: I added a fith hint and also made an addition to hint 4. I hope someone will solve it now ;)

Comment: The final hint pointed me to go back and try and idea I had two weeks ago using a different method.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

So the Answer is

> **Ice Age**.

You start off

> plotting the tickets to a seating plan which puts them all next to each other and spells out `THE TIMES WILL POINT TO IT` using the first letter of each movie on the ticket.

You then use that order to

> use a clock face to map out the hour and minute hands to form two words. The hour hand spells out `ICE` and the minute hand spells out `AGE`.

Below are the steps taken over the weeks it took to work this out!

---

> Plotting the clocks on a seating plan map puts them in a trail but I can't make out any more than that yet: http://jsfiddle.net/7tdhvysu/5/

EDIT 1:

> The first one is on row 3 and points to the 1, the second is on row 4 and also points to the 1, and the next one down points to the 5. These are the starting numbers for pi: `3.1415...`, which points to `The Life of Pi`

EDIT 2:

> Reversing the order of the rows doesn't help: http://jsfiddle.net/8rbd5pv9/

EDIT 3

> There are a number of them with the same minutes right next to each other, in fact there are 6 "pairs" of same minute hands next to each other - perhaps relevant? One of those pairs contains "12" minutes, which is abnormal to the others which are all multiples of 5.

EDIT 4:

> Based upon the two hints, it would appear that the film title relates to a number. Clockwork Orange also screams out at this point so I wonder if *somehow* the numbers of the times are able to be formed to produce the hex code for Orange?

EDIT 5:

> Not the answer (based upon hints) but "The times will point to it" could indicate Shutter Island, as the time for that is 2:15 and the HTML code for the "times" symbol is `&#215;`, however the one *that* points to is WALL-E so that could also be an answer.

Edit 6 - ANSWER!?

> Is the film "Ice Age"?

> I used a clock face to map out the minute hands and it printed out what looked like "Age". Looking at the hour hands it looks like if I did the same I would get "Ice".
>  [image: image1]

EDIT 7:

> Ice Age is definitely the answer!
>  [image: image2]
>
>  Really annoying that I tried this about two weeks ago but I used the actual clocks from my JSFiddle and nothing showed up. It's also technically not correct to use analogue as some of the comments suggest, because if a minute hand is pointing to the 10 or 11, then the hour hand is nearly pointing the next number. That is partly what threw me before when I was trying to line up the hour hands in my JSFiddle!

Comment: The trail order is the same order that you use to pluck off the first letters of the titles to get the message @generalcrispy pointed out.  I'm wondering if the hands pointing would make more sense in a "times point to it" if in your chart you had the lower numbered rows at the bottom instead of starting them at the top

Comment: @Dason See Edit 2

Comment: This occurrence of pi is mere coincidence, but interesting find! Ordering the clocks by the seat numbers is the right way. You need to find a way to use the information of the clocks together with that order.

Comment: @formica edit 4 added

Comment: @JamieBarker Good idea, but completely on the wrong track.

Comment: @formica Another interesting point in edit #5

Comment: @JamieBarker You want it to be something with hex, ASCII, HTML code or the like, don't you? But the way to the solution is far more analog.

Comment: @formica I dont _want_ it to be anything, I was just looking at all avenues and stumbled across that :)

Comment: @JamieBarker I only aimed to push you towards the right direction ;). Keep on trying! I didn't think it would take so long for someone to find the solution after this question got so much attention. But I guess it's always easy if you know the solution...

Comment: @formica Do I have the answer!?

Comment: @JamieBarker Absolutely right, good job! Yes, I admit it is a problem, that the position of the hour hands change with the minutes. But when I plotted it, I thought it still would be recognizeable. Even though I had two lines too much for the hours, which I hid in the "_I_", but that works only, if you ignore the minutes.

Comment: Congratulations!! You solved a very difficult puzzle

Comment: Good, I can finally put this puzzle away. SO glad someone finally solved the darn thing.

Comment: Nice answer, but I'm withholding my +1 until an edit is made to the answer to make it easier - and immedieately - undestandable for people just browsing in and reading first question and then the answer. Thie **final** answer should be here, not the full chronology of trials. At least, the **final** answer should pop out most clearly. And It could use a bit better explanation of how the mapping is done as well. As said: Great puzzle, great solution - but the solution post is not yet great.

Comment: @BmyGuest and edit it yourself ;)

Comment: How do you know how to arrange the clock hands in order spell out letters? It's not clear how you figured out how to transpose the angled lines in such a way to spell out the answer.

Comment: @NuclearWang Technically it was generalcrispy that worked that out before I even got here. See the link to the JSFiddle that I created to see what happens when you plot the seating plan.

Answer (score 34):

Partial answer:

> I did a little rearranging by seat number, and the first letters of the movies spell out THE TIMES WILL POINT TO IT.

Comment: If you rot13: nirentr gur fgneg gvzrf, lbh neevir jvgu fvkgrra-avargrra, bar zvahgr orsber Yvsr bs Cv fgnegf, fb gung pbhyq or vg...

Comment: Well done! This is exactly the first step to take to solve this puzzle.

Answer (score 7):

I tried too rearrange then draw the clocks:

> [image]

Comment: https://www.helpingwithmath.com/printables/worksheets/time/3md1-clock-face-generator01.htm

Comment: rot13( Unf nalbar gevrq gnxvat gur pybpxf, naq neenatvat gurz fb gur ubhef cbvag gb ubhef, be zvahgrf gb zvahgrf )

Comment: Not sure if it matters or not, but I think you might have La La Land and Life of Pi reversed.

Comment: Your approach is right, but you still need to find a way to use the information of the clocks.

Comment: I'm going to guess that rearranging the clocks in the right half of your diagram correctly will cause the clock hands to spell out a movie title.

Comment: @Harfatum How do you even get letters from those clock faces, much less a full title?

Comment: Anything to do with [flag semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_semaphore)?

Comment: @abl No, it uses no flag semaphore.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the arrows pointing to numbers, and those numbers referring to letters of the alphabet or letters in the corresponding movie tickets? That’s the only thing I can think of, but I don’t really see how that uses the ‘analog’ thing.

Comment: @SPK.z It has to do with the clock hands. But it is not important _what_ they are pointing to.

Answer (score 6):

Potential partial answer building on generalcrispy's [partial answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/75145/53907):

> I tried drawing the times for an analog clock and noticed that the hour arms usually point more or less directly at another clock (Except those that point out of the image), but i have not been able to establish any kind of pattern, but thought this might save others some time or give them ideas. Maybe they need to be rearranged?
>  The minute arms doesn't seem to point at anything in this configuration
>  [[image]

Comment: The first and last ones are off. (18:25 is shown as 18:45 and 18:40 is shown as 20:40). Kudos, though on "newspaperman" going all analog! :)

Comment: Hm, I thought this might be something in flag semaphore, but some of the times don't map well onto any letter, and the ones that do don't seem to be spelling anything.

Comment: The OP didn't mention that the tickets were laid out on a board. Can we be sure that the ticket arrangement is relevant?

Comment: "Going analog" is indeed the right way, but as @Strawberry suspected, the arrangement on the picture is irrelevant (see new hint). Find another order!

Answer (score 3):

Building off @generalcrispy's answer (you were SO close if I'm right):

> "THE TIMES WILL POINT TO **IT**." (Emphasis added)

So the movie you'll be watching is:

> *IT* (Scary!)

Comment: Seems odd to have a hidden message referencing the times if they're actually irrelevant.

Comment: Could be a red herring?

Comment: @NuclearWang see my comment to generalcrispy as an alternate possibility.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is

> Ocean's eleven? Because it starts around 9:55 pm and you are invited for movie night.

Comment: It could be 'night' at any time past 6pm.

Comment: Its extreme northerly location means [Murmansk](https://www.esquire.com/uk/food-drink/travel/news/a8090/the-arctic-circles-month-long-polar-winter/) experiences an annual 40-day long polar "night" from 3 December to 11 January.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to watch the classic:

> Hot Shots

because

> there are 2 sets of times that are duplicates:
>  12:05 and 12:30

these are:

> The Third Man, 
>  Harold and Maude, 
>  Over the hedge,
>  Shutter Island,

Which is formed by

> Taking the 1st letter of each movie (SHOT) and using each letter twice, getting HOTSHOTS

Comment: There's also Toy Story 2 and Edward Scissorhands (18:25).

Comment: of course.. could we gracefully ignore that fact?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to watch:

> Titanic

Because

> Graph the seats, they form a continuous line of an object.  Rotate that object (i.e. assume the first and last points are at the same level) and it's an iceberg.

Comment: With Clue#1, clearly this is wrong. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think it is

> La La Land

because

> The seat and row numbers add to 15, the exact start time of the movie.  None of the other tickets' seat/row numbers add up in this way.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried my best to evaluate each ticket on similarity basis bcos two ticket are required to watch the movie.But no similarity is found as far as row & seat no is concerned. Only similarity is found in timing of movies. So on the similarity of timing I can conclude that they will go one of 
> following movies
> 1 Edward Scissors Hands timing 18.25 
> 2 Toy Story 2   timing 18.25
> Moreover there seats are in line one behind other.